# sigma algebra generated by a collection of r.v

Tags: measure-theory

I am struggling to show  the following:

$\sigma(X_1,X_2,....X_n)=\sigma(\cup_{1,..n}\bf F_n)$  , where $\sigma(X_n)=\bf F_n$.

Not sure how to express $\sigma(X_1,X_2,....X_n)$. Any help will be appreciable

Comment: Use the definition: it's the smallest sigma-algebra such that $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are measurable. Thus, show that either sigma algebra is contained in one-another. It might help to show that you can generate the latter sigma algebra by unions of multidimensional rectangles.

Comment: Yah , i can get the argument going from LHS to RHS. How about the other direction. if A belong to RHS how we can show A also belongs to LHS?

Comment: Generate the r.h.s. via multidimensional rectangles and show that each rectangle is contained in the l.h.s.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your suggestion. Are you using the fact that any set that belongs to RHS can be generated by Rectangles?

Comment: Yes, exactly, combined with the fact that it's the smallest sigma-algebra.